# How can I extract a specific object from a list of objects in a single row of an ArrayAdapter in Android?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have an `ArrayAdapter` called `BTArrayAdapter` & I'm trying to add two different Objects to it, one being a `String` and another one being a `BluetoothDevice` in a single row.

Following is my code:

```
if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) 
{   

    BluetoothDevice btd = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    BTArrayAdapter.add( btd.getName() + btd.getAddress() + btd);
}
```

**Question is**

How will I get a specific object from a single row?

`BTArrayAdapter.getItem(position)` returns a single row containing **both**, the `String` & the `BluetoothDevice`, how can I extract only the **BluetooothDevice** from it?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: May I know why this question has been voted down? I went through the documentation of `ArrayAdapter`, couldn't find what I was looking for & that's why I posted it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create class like:

```
class BlueToothContainer{

   public String adress;
   public String name;
   public BluetoothDevice device;

   //constructor etc..
}
```

Then your adapter should work on List of BlueToothContainers, thanks that you will get object and get from it only device, or only name etc.

```
BTArrayAdapter.getItem(position).device //it is BluetoothDevice
```

PS. ofcource your class should have private properties and getters to it, i writed this class on example.